# To Get the radio button value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a quiz and display that questions one per page as partial form and when i use the create i want the value of radio button that i check before create. when i use params[:answer]in my controller next, it returns null.. can anyone help me out to get the value of radio button that i checked

Thanks in advance

```
<div class = "y">
<% form_for @answer do |f|%>
<div class = "label_field_pair">
<label for "questions">
  <%= @ans.ques %>
</label>  
</div> <br>
<div class = "label_field_pair2">
<label for "options">
  <div id = "option-1">
    <%= radio_button_tag "answer", "#{@ans.id}ans1"%><%= @ans.ans1 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-2">
    <%= radio_button_tag "answer", "#{@ans.id}ans2"%><%= @ans.ans2 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-3">
    <%= radio_button_tag "answer", "#{@ans.id}ans3"%><%= @ans.ans3 %>
  </div><br>
  <div id = "option-4">
    <%= radio_button_tag "answer", "#{@ans.id}ans4"%><%= @ans.ans4  %>
  </div><br>
</label>
  </div>
 <div class="next">
  <%= link_to_remote "Next", 
    :before => "Element.show('loader')",
    :success => "Element.hide('loader')",
    :url=>{:controller=>"answers", :action=>"next"},
    :with => "'&passed_question=#{@ans.id}&'+'&exam_group_id=#{@exam_group.id}&'"
  %> 
<% end %>
 </div> 
<% end %> 
</div>
```

and in controller

```
def next
@user = current_user
@student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
@exam_group = ExamGroup.find_by_id(params[:exam_group_id])
@answer = Answer.new(params[:ans])
@answer.answer = params[:answer]
@answer.exam_group_id = @exam_group.id
@answer.user_id = @user.id
passed_question = params[:passed_question]
@answer.questions_id = passed_question
if @answer.save
  @ans = Question.find_by_id(left_random, :conditions => ['id not in (?) && exam_group_id=?',answered, @exam_group])
    render(:update) do |page|
      page.replace_html 'main', :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
    end
end
end
def ans
@user = current_user
@student = Student.find_by_admission_no(@user.username)
@exam_group = ExamGroup.find(params[:exam_group_id])
@tot_ans = answered.count
@last_ques = (Question.count-1)
render(:update) do |page|
  page.replace_html @ans, :partial => 'ans', :object => @ans
end
end
```

Comment: Your form_for specifies `@answer`, but the radio buttons are part of `@ans`.

Comment: Seeing your params would be a big help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140176/saving-radio-buttons-values-in-rails

Comment: Actually link_to_remote next is the post and create a answer database in that ans returns null.... in my development log Processing AnswersController#next (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-15 19:51:25) [POST]
  Parameters: {"passed_question"=>"3", "action"=>"next", "authenticity_token"=>"EjReUuUVAbRJ6s3k7Tj/pS7s2ENUUgTvyaiiRz9/IF8=", "exam_group_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"answers"}                     in this i want answer parameter which is given in radio button to get the result

Answer (score 0):

You need "f" before your radio button inputs would be a start, but your controller code looks quite inefficient at first glance:

```
 <%= f.radio_button :answer, "#{@ans.id}ans1" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `link_to_remote` next is the post and create a answer database in that ans returns `null`.... 
in my development log Processing `AnswersController#next` (for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-15 19:51:25)

```
[POST] Parameters: {"passed_question"=>"3", "action"=>"next", "authenticity_token"=>"EjReUuUVAbRJ6s3k7Tj/pS7s2ENUUgTvyaiiRz9/IF8=", "exam_group_id"=>"1", "controller"=>"answers"}
```

in this i want answer parameter which is given in radio button to get the result