# Print the radio button value in next page in ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am using 2 radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio0" name="answer[16]" value="Domestic" checked>
<label for="radio0">Domestic</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="answer[16]" value="International">
<label for="radio1">International</label>
```

I want to print these selected radio button value in the next page like :

Usage of Documents: Domestic

any idea how to implement this in ruby?

I have seen this eg in stackoverflow. But getting little bit confused as how to implement in my code:
Discussion of the stackoverflow is below:
[To Get the radio button value in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380806/to-get-the-radio-button-value-in-ruby-on-rails)

```
<div id = "option-1">
  <%= radio_button_tag "answer", "#{@ans.id}ans1"%><%= @ans.ans1 %>
</div>

<%= f.radio_button :answer, "#{@ans.id}ans1" %>
```

Comment: Are you storing radio button value in db while navigating to next page ?

Comment: @dkp the value is getting stored in the aswer[16}

Comment: Instance variables do not carry over between controller actions so you'll need to either store this selection in the database or if it's not meant to be permanent you can store it in the session or params hashes.